# JavaScript selectionchange-EventListener, triggering infinitely on document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, selectionchanged, designmode

I have added an event listener for `selectionchange` as below,

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", 
function()
{
    highlight();
    console.log("selectionchange-triggered");
}, false);
```

then I have added the below code, to highlight selected text.

```
function highlight()
{
    document.designMode = "on";
    document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#ff0000");
    document.designMode = "off";
}
```

When the highlight function is called, the `EventListener` for selectionchange is fired infinitely until I clear the selection.

have any one faced the same issue ? can any one suggest a solution to solve this issue ?

Comment: why dont you use then `selectstart` and `selectend`?

Comment: let me check that works..

Comment: @Mephiztopheles:Can I set event listener for selectStart and selectEnd?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: I found in Microsoft website that, event listener cane be set for selectstart, but I am working on Safari, is that available for Safari ?

Comment: @Mephiztopheles I tried setting it on Safari, but not working.

Comment: Ok, maybe it will help if you have a look at the selectstart event like jquery it binds. so.. what i mean is, go to jquery.com and download the uncompressed version, and search for the selectstart reerence... maybe they're working different in safari

Comment: Ok..thx…I will try...

Comment: I'll look for more when I'm home

Comment: @Mephiztopheles ok…thx...

Comment: I found this: http://help.dottoro.com/ljnactnw.php
They say, safari should support it

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: but I have tried the same above code, but replaced "selectionchange" with "selectstart" and "selectend", but the event listener was not fired i.e. no logs like "selectionchange-triggered".

Comment: @Mephiztopheles:I was put the highlight() function call inside that event handler. Now I have removed it and called it on button click event, so now the infinite loop is not there. I think, the problem is that, the execCommand triggers selectionchange event, don't know why ? Anyway Thx for the help...

Comment: is your wish to have a different selection background than default?  There is a way in css to do it: `::selection {background: #ff0000}` , `::-moz-selection {background: #ff0000}`

Comment: Check this out, man : http://jsfiddle.net/rzmstcot/

Comment: the selectstart works on desktop Safari, but not on mobile Safari. I tried http://jsfiddle.net/rzmstcot/ also in mobile Safari, the event is not fired.

Comment: aaah, mobile .. thats another point... i'll look around

Comment: There is no `selectend` event. `selectionchange` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a simple flag to prevent the infinite loop. The `window.setTimeout()` call is there because the `selectionchange` event doesn't fire synchronously when `document.execCommand()` is called.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rzmstcot/5/

Code:

```
var highlighting = false;

function highlight()
{
    document.designMode = "on";
    highlighting = true;
    document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#ff0000");
    document.designMode = "off";
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        highlighting = false;
    }, 1);
}

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", 
function()
{
    if (!highlighting) {
        highlight();
    }
    console.log("selectionchange-triggered");
}, false);
```

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: No, I didn't check it. I should have said so in the answer.

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: Fixed now.

Comment: Not bad ;) I was looking for a solutuon without extra variables, but it seems to be the best way, when mobile safari doesn't support selectstart

Comment: The infinite event firing is not there now, but sometimes Mobile Safari crashes. Don't know exact scenario, but it was when selecting all text or on moving the selection control continuously for some time.